# Flow keeps restarting when 'Finished' event is handled

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-communities, salesforce-flow

Well, I have a problem with the redirection of a flow. My problem is that when the flow returns the status 'Finished' and I treat it with the necessary logic in my case, it is relaunched. I can see how with the logs after 'finished' you see a 'Started', the first screen is shown and then it redirects to run 'window.parent.location.href = '{!FinishPageAPCMatch}';' correctly. If you control the 'finished' event it's not supposed to relaunch, right? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MIpo.png)

I tried to add finishLocation attributte and finishbehaviour